# I couldn't make my footer sticky

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make a sticky footer for my website. i tried http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/'s method and a few others, nothing works. here's my code with the cssstickyfooter.com one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<!--[if !IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
    #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<style type="text/css">
* {margin:0;padding:0;} 

html {height: 100%;}

body {
height: 100%;
color: #131212;
background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
padding-bottom: 26px;}  

#footer {position: relative;
margin-top: -26px; 
height: 26px;
clear:both;
background-color: #b0b0b0} 

body:before {
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;
}

h1 {
font-size: 350%
}
h6 {
font-size: 40%
}

a:link {
color: #5e5e5e;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #5e5e5e;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #5e5e5e;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<center>
        <div id="header">
        <h1>my header here</h1>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="main">
            <h2>my content here</h2>
        </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <h3>my footer here</h3>
    </div>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

what's wrong with this?

edit-a jsfiddle of this
http://jsfiddle.net/2WwZf/

this works fine:

```
 <div id="wrap">
 <center>
    <div id="header">
    <h1>my header here</h1>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="main">
        <h2>my content here</h2>
    </div>
 </center>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
 <h3>my footer here</h3>
 </div>
```

but when i do this, it still fails.

```
 <center>
 <div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
    <h1>my header here</h1>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="main">
        <h2>my content here</h2>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
 <h3>my footer here</h3>
 </div>
 </center>
```

Comment: You can always create a JSFiddle with the code you already have. This will make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `footer` div needs to be outside of the `wrap` div, like so:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
    <h1>my header here</h1>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="main">
        <h2>my content here</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <h3>my footer here</h3>
</div>
```

You can also remove the `<center>` tags and just apply a style of `text-align:center` to the elements you want to center.

```
#wrap {
       min-height: 100%;
       text-align:center;
      }

#footer {
         position: relative;
         margin-top: -26px; 
         height: 26px;
         clear:both;
         background-color: #b0b0b0;
         text-align:center;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "makes it fail"? If you are just trying to center your content, why not just apply a style of `text-align:center` to the applicable elements? [Here is a fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTdf5/) that works.

Comment: i meant when i tried to center the footer with <center>, it went back up. but text-align:center works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your footer's parent element needs to have full height (either window or content, depending on which one is bigger). Also, it needs to be positioned explicitly (`relative` in your case) for your absolutely positioned footer to be positioned in relation to it.

Here's a working example, based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/z3C3F/2/

Important CSS lines:

```
center {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```